# Recursively concatenate passed string

Tags: javascript, class, recursion

I'm writing a BST in JS and trying to concatenate a string passed into a member function without success. `console.log()` works but it automatically starts a new line for each entry.

```
"use strict";

class Node {
    constructor(dt) {
        this.data = dt;
        this.left = null;
        this.right = null;
    }
}

class BST {
    constructor() {
        this.root = null;
    }
    insert(parent, key) {
        if (!this.root) return this.root = new Node(key);
        else {
            if (key < parent.data) {
                if (!parent.left) {
                    parent.left = new Node(key);
                } else {
                    this.insert(parent.left, key);
                }
            } else if (key > parent.data) {
                if (!parent.right) {
                    parent.right = new Node(key);
                } else {
                    this.insert(parent.right, key);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    // Doesn't work
    printIN(parent, string) {
        if (parent) {
            this.printIN(parent.left);
            console.log(parent.data);
            string += " " + parent.data;
            // return string += " " + parent.data;
            this.printIN(parent.right);
        }
        return string;
    }
    
    // This works.
    // printIN(parent) {
    //     if (parent) {
    //         this.printIN(parent.left);
    //         console.log(parent.data);
    //         this.printIN(parent.right);
    //     }
    // }
}


let treeA = new BST();
let tree = null;

tree = treeA.insert(treeA.root, 5);
tree = treeA.insert(treeA.root, 7);
tree = treeA.insert(treeA.root, 3);
tree = treeA.insert(treeA.root, 14);


let string = [""];
string = treeA.printIN(treeA.root, string);
console.log();
console.log(string);

// treeA.printIN(treeA.root);
```

I want to print out the numbers on one single line, instead of them starting on a new line each time. I thought using string concatenation is the logical solution, but I can't seem to make it work.

```
    // Doesn't work
    printIN(parent, string) {
        if (parent) {
            this.printIN(parent.left);
            console.log(parent.data);
            string += " " + parent.data;
            // return string += " " + parent.data;
            this.printIN(parent.right);
        }
        return string;
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm not really clear on what's supposed to happen here. What output do you want and what are you getting?

Comment: I want to print out the numbers as a list on a single line. I thought passing on a string to the member function and concatenate it recursively might work. Sorry if I wasn't clear in my OP.

Comment: OK, thanks, so I assume `5 7 3 14`? `let string = [""];` creates an array with an empty string as the first element, not a string. Probably your idea is to use the array to "pass by reference", if so, use `string[0]` to "dereference" it, although this is somewhat of an antipattern but should work in a pinch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another answer gave you a solution to your string problem.  The snippet below has an alternative.  But more importantly, it offers some significant clean-up to your OOP approach.

There are two main reasons this is necessary.

First, you have member functions of your object, which still require the object to be passed to them.  That's redundant and confusing.  Any OOP function which doesn't make reference to `this` should be a static function.  But if you're going to do OOP (I might argue against it in fact), then you shouldn't use static functions as though they were methods.  Thus `insert` and `printIN` should not have the `parent` parameter.

Second, you are dealing with a recursive structure.  Nodes of a tree should have the same design as the tree itself.  This makes all sorts of things easier.  But you have a class `Node` and one called `BST`.  And `BST` then has a `root` node, which should then be recursive.  There is simply no reason for this that I can see.  A BST by nature *is* a root node, with a `data` value (usually, although we can make that optional as you do) and potentially `left` and `right` nodes that are themselves BSTs.

Fixing the code to work like this simplifies it substantially.  Here is one implementation:

```js
class BST {
    constructor(data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
  
    insert(key) {
        if (!this.data) {
            this.data = key;
        } else {
            if (key < this.data) {
                if (!this.left) {
                    this.left = new BST(key);
                } else {
                    this.left.insert(key);
                }
            } else if (key > this.data) {
                if (!this.right) {
                    this.right = new BST(key);
                } else {
                    this.right.insert(key);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    printIN() {
        return (this.left ? this.left.printIN() + ' ' : '') +
               this.data +
               (this.right ? ' ' + this.right.printIN() : ''); 
    }
}


let treeA = new BST();

treeA.insert(5);
treeA.insert(7);
treeA.insert(3);
treeA.insert(14);

console.log(treeA.printIN());
```

There is no `Node` class here.  Everything is done in `BST`.  Moreover, `BST` objects don't need a `root` node and the methods are simpler.

I would note, though that `printIN` is less useful than another function which we could use the same way:

```js
    toArray() {
        return [
            ...(this.left ? this.left.toArray() : []), 
            this.data, 
            ...(this.right ? this.right.toArray() : [])
        ];
    }
```

which would allow

```js
console.log(treeA.toArray()); //=> [3, 5, 7, 14]
```

and you could get your string just by `join`ing that array with a space.  This function strikes me as much more useful than the printIN one you have.

We could also add a static function:

```js
    static fromArray(xs) {
        return xs .reduce (function (tree, x) {
            tree.insert(x)
            return tree
        }, new BST())
    }
```

that would allow us to write

```js
tree = BST .fromArray ([8, 6, 7, 5, 3, 0, 9]);
tree .printIN() //=> [0, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

---

I mentioned that I wouldn't even do this with OOP.  But I don't do much that way these days, preferring functional approaches.  So, if you're curious, here's another take on the problem altogether, using just functions, and trees that aren't modified when you do an `insert`, but instead return new trees:

```js
const bst = (xs) => 
  xs .reduce ((tree, x) => bstInsert (x, tree), {})

const bstInsert = (x, {left, data, right} = {}) => 
  data == undefined
    ? {data: x}
    : x < data
      ? {data, left: bstInsert (x, left), ...(right ? {right} : {})}
      : {data, ...(left ? {left} : {}), right: bstInsert (x, right)}

const inorder = ({left, data, right} = {}) => [
  ...(left ? inorder(left) : []), 
  data, 
  ...(right ? inorder(right) : [])
]

inorder (bst ([8, 6, 7, 5, 3, 0, 9])) //=> [0, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

I'm not recommending that technique, specifically, but FP can be a powerful alternative to OOP.

Comment: Thank you craftmeister! I didn't expect to get such an amazingly detailed response! I love the fp snippet at the end, such a terse yet beautiful way of writing. This is why I love JS!

Answer (score 1):

Try this technique.

```js
printIN(parent, result = []) {
    if (parent) {
        this.printIN(parent.left, result);
        result.push(parent.data)
        this.printIN(parent.right, result);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Pass, as a second argument, the array of strings that will serve as the resulting list of node values as per the in-order bst traversal.

Use a default value for this argument of `[]` then, if omitted, one will be created, but when recursing, you can pass the existing array in.  When you visit a node, push the value into the array.  Call `printIN` on the root node and do not provide the `result` argument (a new array will be created and returned).

If you want to log all on one line, use [Array.prototype.join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to transform the array of strings into a single comma-separated string, and log that.

Working example:

```js
class Node {
    constructor(dt) {
        this.data = dt;
        this.left = null;
        this.right = null;
    }
}

class BST {
    constructor() {
        this.root = null;
    }
    insert(parent, key) {
        if (!this.root) return this.root = new Node(key);
        else {
            if (key < parent.data) {
                if (!parent.left) {
                    parent.left = new Node(key);
                } else {
                    this.insert(parent.left, key);
                }
            } else if (key > parent.data) {
                if (!parent.right) {
                    parent.right = new Node(key);
                } else {
                    this.insert(parent.right, key);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    printIN(parent, result = []) {
        if (parent) {
            this.printIN(parent.left, result);
            result.push(parent.data)
            this.printIN(parent.right, result);
        }
        return result;
    }
}


let treeA = new BST();
let tree = null;

tree = treeA.insert(treeA.root, 5);
tree = treeA.insert(treeA.root, 7);
tree = treeA.insert(treeA.root, 3);
tree = treeA.insert(treeA.root, 14);


console.log(treeA.printIN(treeA.root).join());
```